# How can I use different layout in android orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I want to use a separate layout for my fragment on landscape view , hence I have created a separate layout for landscape view . But the problem is when I rotate the screen `onConfigurationChanged` , `onDestroyView` `onDestroy` called sequentially . And it backs to previous fragment . I can prevent it by using `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` on my activity . But in this case , the view remains same it doesn't use my separate layout , it is just stretched to fill the screen . Is there any way so that I can use separate layout while using  `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your issue is quite generic,

If you disable the `orientation` and make it a constant to `portrait/landscape`, the changes in `orientation` of the `device` (phone) will not force the activity to be re-created. so even though you have separate layout for fragment it will not be loaded,

and if you make `orientation` of activity depending on the orientation change to the `device` (Phone) it will re-create the activity due to which you `activity` will initialize everything as result you are getting the first fragment while rotating the screen.

to deal with it, what you can do is use `savedInstanceState`(`Bundle`) while recreating the activity,

save the current fragment you have loaded and mention that to your `savedInstanceState`(`Bundle`) and after re-creating the activity when the orientation is changed, read the `savedInstanceState` and you will know which `fragment` to load

Comment: I understand . How could I save the current fragment ? Should I do it in my activity or in my fragment file . Both fragment and activity has

 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
but `outState` only let me put several types of variable like array, string, int etc , how can I save the whole fragment state? One more thing in my fragment I have calling a lot of api .

Comment: @Suv, you will save a number(or a String) in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`  of activity denoting which was the fragment loaded last, eg... 1 for fragment_1, 2 for fragment_2 .. and load the respective fragment when your activity is recreated when it changes the orientation.......... ......... 

After this has been done save the state for the fragment in the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) ` of the fragment in the fragment this is optional if you want to do it

Answer (score 3):

To use different layouts use different resourse folders:
That is, use `layout` folder for portrait and `layout-lang` for landscape mode.

you can use `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` to detect orientation, then load XML you like something like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
switch (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation) {
                      case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
setContentView(R.layout.aportrait);
                         break;
                      case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
setContentView(R.layout.alandscape);
                         break;
                    }

/////..............
}
```

Comment: I have done it  already , it doesn't do anything if I use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` , but If I remove the `screensize` from `configchagne` , I can see different layout which I have created , but in this case fragment simply destroy

Comment: actually , I am doing it in a fragment and not using a single layout file , my fragment consists of several layout file .

Comment: @Suv , it doesn't matter if you are using fragments or not . this is just an example. You can implement setContentView as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `andorid:configChanges` from manifest. Its purpose is that you yourself is handling configuration changes. Remove it and android will automatically pick the right layout file.

Hope this helps.